# SQL Query to combine values from multiple records into a single column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

In my table each record can have up to 30 different budget Codes.
I need a query that returns all budget codes in the table as a single column.
The query I have errors stating that the subquery returned more than 1 value.

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT [budgetCode1] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode2] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode3] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode4] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode5] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode6] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode7] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode8] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode9] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode10] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode11] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode12] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode13] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode14] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode15] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode16] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode17] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode18] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode19] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode20] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode21] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode22] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode23] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode24] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode25] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode26] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode27] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode28] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode29] FROM TABLE_NAME),
        (SELECT [budgetCode30] FROM TABLE_NAME) AS BudgetCodes
  FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Reconsider your wide database table as this is inefficient storage and will not scale properly. Create a *BudgetCodes* table with foreign key link to *TableName* and maintain **one** column indicator for 1-30 and **one** column indicator for corresponding number or string value.

Comment: As [concluded](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3976) by @RolandMySQLDBA: *There is no substitute or band-aid that can make up for bad design. Please, for your sake of your sanity in the future, normalize that table today !!!*

Comment: I would very much love to normalize my table.  Unfortunately this table is created via a data dump from another system.  I don't get a say in the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is going to return 30 columns and will error if `TABLE_NAME` has more than one record. Instead, you want to use a UNION query here:

```
    SELECT [budgetCode1] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode2] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode3] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode4] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode5] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode6] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode7] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode8] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode9] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode10] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode11] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode12] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode13] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode14] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode15] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode16] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode17] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode18] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode19] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode20] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode21] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode22] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode23] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode24] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode25] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode26] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode27] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode28] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode29] FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode30] FROM TABLE_NAME
```

You can also add in which budgetcode column this was derived from:

```
    SELECT [budgetCode1],"budgetCode1" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode2],"budgetCode2" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode3],"budgetCode3" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode4],"budgetCode4" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode5],"budgetCode5" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode6],"budgetCode6" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode7],"budgetCode7" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode8],"budgetCode8" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode9],"budgetCode9" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode10],"budgetCode10" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode11],"budgetCode11" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode12],"budgetCode12" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode13],"budgetCode13" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode14],"budgetCode14" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode15],"budgetCode15" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode16],"budgetCode16" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode17],"budgetCode17" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode18],"budgetCode18" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode19],"budgetCode19" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode20],"budgetCode20" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode21],"budgetCode21" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode22],"budgetCode22" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode23],"budgetCode23" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode24],"budgetCode24" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode25],"budgetCode25" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode26],"budgetCode26" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode27],"budgetCode27" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode28],"budgetCode28" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode29],"budgetCode29" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [budgetCode30],"budgetCode30" as budgetcode FROM TABLE_NAME AS BudgetCodes
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: We SQL folks need to highlight suboptimal database design like this which leads to tedious, complex queries!

Comment: @Parfait Totally Agree. Having columns for each budget code is a poor choice and is going to lead to some nasty (and slow) union queries to put it in the proper format (like we are doing here). Yuck.

Comment: Can this query be modified to exclude NULL or empty string values?

Comment: You'll have to wrap it up in a subquery and add a WHERE clause `WHERE [budgetcode1] IS NULL` or.. add that WHERE clause to every individual SELECT statement.